# XML (TEI document) parsing in R: how can I extract only the head?

Tags: r, xpath, xml-parsing, tei

I have to parse a XML-TEI document similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
<teiHeader> ... </teiHeader>
<text>
 <body>
  <head rend="Body A">DOCUMENT_TITLE</head>
    <div rend="entry">
    <head rend="time">TIME_INFORMATION</head>
    <p rend="Body A"> INFORMATION A</p>
    <p rend="content">
        <hi rend="italic"> CONTENT </hi>
            </p>
    </div>
```

I would like to extract the TIME_INFORMATION string. Can someone give some advice please?

I am able to get easily the CONTENT with the command

```
doc <- htmlParse(paste0(mypath,xml_path))
content<-unlist(xpathSApply(doc,'//p[@rend="content"]//hi[@rend="italic"]',xmlValue))
```

But how can I extract only the TIME_INFORMATION? I tried

```
doc <- htmlParse(paste0(mypath,xml_path))
content<-unlist(xpathSApply(doc,'//div//head[@rend="time"]',xmlValue))
```

but I obtain an empty list.
The only way I found is to get the whole body of each entry "div" and parse the dates with regular expressions but I would like to avoid this.

Anyway, doing this I notice that when I run:

```
div <- getNodeSet(doc2, '//div')
```

I obtain a slightly different structure of the original XML, seems that the tag  disappeared. For instance, `div[1]` is:

```
> div[1]
[[1]]
<div rend="entry">
        London, June 19th, 1854.
        <p rend="Body A">Oxford, University Archive </p>
        <p rend="content">
            <hi rend="italic"> CONTENT </hi></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you share a valid XML file? This one is truncated.

Comment: instead of trying to parse the XML, is it worth using `readLines()` and looking for the string `<head rend="time">`?

Answer (score 2):

**1)** The XML is malformed (missing ending tags). Also since a namespace is used (as per second line of input -- the line beginning with TEI) we must refer to it in xpath.  `Lines` is taken from the question without modification and also shown in the Note at the end.

```
library(xml2)
doc <- Lines |> 
  paste("</body></text></TEI>") |>
  read_xml()

xml_ns(doc)
## d1 <-> http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0

xml_find_first(doc, 'normalize-space(//d1:head[@rend="time"])')
## [1] "TIME_INFORMATION"
```

**2)** Another approach is to use `xml_ns_strip` to strip out the namespaces so that we can avoid dealing with them. Using `doc` from above

```
doc |>
  xml_ns_strip() |>
  xml_find_first('normalize-space(//head[@rend="time"])')
## [1] "TIME_INFORMATION"
```

### Note

```
Lines <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
<teiHeader> ... </teiHeader>
<text>
 <body>
  <head rend="Body A">DOCUMENT_TITLE</head>
    <div rend="entry">
    <head rend="time">TIME_INFORMATION</head>
    <p rend="Body A"> INFORMATION A</p>
    <p rend="content">
        <hi rend="italic"> CONTENT </hi>
            </p>
    </div>
'
```

### Update

Have improved solution.